# HTML-код как текст при нажатии на кнопку "Назад"

Tags: php, nginx, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Использую PrestaShop 1.7.2.4

Проблема была воспроизведена как в Chrome на Windows, так и в Chrome на Android.

При просмотре товаров иногда (но все же достаточно часто), когда нажимаю на кнопку "Назад" в браузере, вижу вместо привычного дизайна JSON как текст:

```
{"rendered_products_top":"<div id=\"js-product-list-top\" class=\"row products-selection\"> ....... "}
// И так далее...
```

Появляться это стало после НГ. Никаких работ не делал. По сути сейчас вернулся к работе над сайтом и стал замечать такое поведение.

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Ошибка достаточно популярна в 1.7 даже на есть на оф.супорте тема, но решение и и справление в новых версиях Престы пока нету. Вот сама тема  http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-3909

Comment: @klifort круто. А есть предположения как тестируют PS разработчики перед релизом?

Comment: чесно говоря незнаю. но думаю з таким подходом люди скоро уйдут с престы, на вукомерс, но и там на сколько я знаю начиная с 5.0 вордпресса будет "интересно"....